# cURL vs Postman, different responses to HTTPS POST

Tags: ssl, curl, postman, tls1.2

We are setting up a reporting feed to a client and, in testing out the endpoint, we are receiving different responses between cURL (command-line) and Postman.  In Postman, the request goes through, just fine; we get a 200-OK back.  However, when we send the request in cURL, we get the following response back `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired`

### With cURL

The cURL request looks like the following:

```
curl -i -H "content-type: application/json" -d '{"foo": [],"bar": [],"baz": []}' https://test.example.com/notARealEndpoint
```

### With Postman

The Postman setup is hard to display, but it's code-conversion looks like:

**cURL interpretation**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://test.example.com/not/aReal/Endpoint' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' --data-raw '{"foo": [],"bar": [],"baz": []}'
```

**This, by the way, returns the same `certificate has expired` error when run in command line*

**HTTP interpretation**

```
POST /not/aReal/Endpoint HTTP/1.1
Host: test.example.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: text/plain

{"foo": [],"bar": [],"baz": []}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a bit dated question but I had the same issue.

Turns out in Postman there is an option to "Follow original HTTP Method" which was for me turned off. After turning it on I get the correct response as with curl

[image]

Comment: I'm going to be honest with you, I feel like I tried all the Settings flags that were available, at the time that I created this question.  But perhaps that's a flag that didn't exist three years ago.

I am no longer in a position to test this -- the company I worked for shut down.  But I hate that this has been unresolved, this whole time.  So we're gonna call this "THE ANSWER".  Thank you @Jamesed for answering an old question. 

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the target server has an expired SSL certificate. The reason that postman is not raising an error couble be because of disabled SSL verification checks.

You can disable those checks in curl by using a `--insecure` or `-k` option.
eg:

```
curl https://expired.badssl.com
```

Will throw the same error that you are seeing.
versus

```
curl --insecure https://expired.badssl.com
```

will return an html response body.

Comment: I am aware that with cURL I can avoid the insecure constraint.  My interest is in what it takes to replicate the same results in Postman.  The reasons are two-fold: 1) to make sure that my toolsets are reliable and interchangable, and 2) to make sure that my argument (for or against action) is more sound than "Tool A has a problem, regardless of Tool B".  Postman has an option to ignore insecure servers.  It is turned off.  So, this may be a bug.  Or it's indicative of another setting, such as a qualifying flag.